# Powershell: Re-Install Printer depending on Username

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to learn Powershell and have no experience in any script language at all (well, except Batch a bit).

What I'm trying to do is to run this Batch command -> `IF "%USERNAME%"=="Admin" GOTO Admin` as a Powershell command and afterwards reinstall the users Default printer. The reason why I Need a goto is because I want to use the same script for several Users. This is what I have so far as a Batch/Powershell Hybrid

```
IF "%USERNAME%"=="Admin" GOTO Admin

:Admin
powershell
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).RemovePrinterConnection("\\Server\adprinter")
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection("\\Server\adprinter")
$printer = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where ShareName = 'adprinter'"
$printer.SetDefaultPrinter()
exit
GOTO eof
```

I'd like to do the whole Thing in powershell but I just don't get it. I read that you can do a "goto" in powershell with a if-loop. for example that's what I have

```
$user = [Environment]::UserName
if ($user = Admin) do {""}
```

But how do I run my commands now? and how do I do another Loop for other usernames?

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT:**

Here is the whole script I have so far. I Need a "goto" because I have more than one User, and each of them Needs his own Printer. It would be nice to transform every Batch command into a powershell command.

```
@echo off

IF "%USERNAME%"=="user1" GOTO user1
IF "%USERNAME%"=="user2" GOTO user2
IF "%USERNAME%"=="user3" GOTO user3
IF "%USERNAME%"=="user4" GOTO user4
IF "%USERNAME%"=="user5" GOTO user5

:user1
powershell
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).RemovePrinterConnection("\\Server\printer1")
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection("\\Server\printer1")
$printer = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where ShareName = 'printer1'"
$printer.SetDefaultPrinter()
exit
GOTO eof

:user2
powershell
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).RemovePrinterConnection("\\Server\printer2")
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection("\\Server\printer2")
$printer = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where ShareName = 'printer2'"
$printer.SetDefaultPrinter()
exit
GOTO eof

:user3
powershell
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).RemovePrinterConnection("\\Server\printer3")
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection("\\Server\printer3")
$printer = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where ShareName = 'printer3'"
$printer.SetDefaultPrinter()
exit
GOTO eof

:user4
powershell
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).RemovePrinterConnection("\\Server\printer4")
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection("\\Server\printer4")
$printer = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where ShareName = 'printer4'"
$printer.SetDefaultPrinter()
exit
GOTO eof

:user5
powershell
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).RemovePrinterConnection("\\Server\printer5")
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection("\\Server\printer5")
$printer = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where ShareName = 'printer5'"
$printer.SetDefaultPrinter()
exit
GOTO eof

:eof
exit
```

Comment: Why do you need a `goto`? Why not just run the code *if* the username is admin? i.e. put the code you appear to have written in the if statement you have also written

Comment: Hi Arco - look @ my edit

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this but I think you'll need to learn some powershell. Firstly you should use a function to do the printer mapping. Then either use a `switch` statement to call the function with the correct user/printer combination, or use a `hashtable` to store the user/printer combination and pass the values in that to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with arco I like the use of HashTables and your issue is perfect for it. Take a look at my code here it should give you a good point for a Powershell Start.

```
$drac = @{ }
Import-Csv \\RemoteServer\Share\Folder\Powershell-scripts\Connect-rac.CSV | ForEach-Object {
    $drac[$_.ServerName] = $_.IMM
}
```

If you look at the above this is what takes my CSV file and loads it into the hashtable

and below if how my code is used, I make it look for the computer name and if the matches then it will return the hashtable value.

```
if ($drac.Contains($ComputerName))
{
    Write-Host "Servername : $ComputerName"
    $URL = $drac[$ComputerName]
    $IE = New-Object -COM 'InternetExplorer.Application'
    $IE.Navigate2("http:\\$URL")
    $IE.Visible = $true
}
```

See if this helps you.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understood it right, but am I going into the right direction with this?

There is already a mistake I think, because it doen't run. 

`$UserName = [Environment]::UserName

$DefPrinter = @{"user1" = "\\srv\prn"; "user2" = "\\srv\prn"; "user3" = "\\srv\prn"; "user4" = "\\srv\prn"; "user5" = "\\srv\prn";}

if ($DefPrinter.Contains($UserName))
{
 (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).RemovePrinterConnection("$DefPrinter.Get_Item($UserName)")
 (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection("$DefPrinter.Get_Item($UserName)") }`

Comment: That is what the CSV is for, so it will be `Column 1 - UserName` `Column 2 - Printer`